# How to save current status for future modif and get back to prev commit and continue work from there?

Tags: git

I have done some changes and I have met a problem, that needs more modifications in the whole code. I want to save the current state as a commit and then get back co previous commit and continue the work from there. I have arrived here, because I thought of doing some improvement, that seems to get bigger.

Doing a commit and then a new branch from the previous commit would be a solution, but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
git checkout -b tmp
git add -A
git commit -m "wip"
git checkout master
```

The first command would create a branch starting in your current commit.
You would then create a new commit with the wip (work in progress).
And you would switch back to your original branch (here, I assume `master`), in order to start working on the problem.